# Create a new table from sql output in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql query which makes a new table with `WITH`.

How can I store that temporary table in my database?
Here is the code:

```
WITH gme AS(
        SELECT distinct seller, buyer, currency, value, cost_type
        FROM iotable
)

SELECT seller, array_agg(buyer), array_agg(cost_type), 
       array_agg(value), array_agg(currency) 
FROM gme 
GROUP by seller
```

Here is the table output:

```
3;"{277,222,276,288,443,445,241,224,280,223,285,5,238,286,278,444,240,287,242,3,8,4}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{2,407,89,6,7,3,36,1212,604,15920,56,11,291,29,1,8,13,4,9,3163,8,356}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
4;"{220,223,421,228,224,277,445,10,237,315,222,238,280,395,246,4,313,8,443,244,242,469,308,219,221,389,444,409,410,9,11,12,227,236,441,225}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{8799,226,5,184,248,37,1,2149,482,154,5745,329,3402,7,105,6443,450,270,3,1070,658,182,1033,932,9091,101,6,1,14,3778,256,1639,2935,1082,9,570}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
5;"{242,441,458,444,6,443,332,456,410,469,439,5,237,313,421,317,241,466,227,445,240,228,423,467,238,438,424}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{1604,12,2,89,10,178,2,3,66,397,5,762,9,4,54,3,118,1,1939,14,20,1090,55,1,273,4,3}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
6;"{444,469,225,226,245,242,228,246,241,237,456,389,441,232,238,227,439,239,240,445,443,6,410,236}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{15,37,54,884,2130,2623,2846,1,323,162,1,1,2,206,981,870,1,2891,150,6,12,171,10,155}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
7;"{390,404,413,400,228,443,370,37,238,280,439,45,441,378,384,369,308,469,437,403,16,456,458,385,47,342,317,7,217,387,313,438,311,397,242}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{68,1,3,1,7,1,2,44,99,325,7,100,1,1,8,2,23,1527,10,740,315,10,2,20,188,1,277,3555,433,10,363,18,224,1,405}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
8;"{46,47,28,237,308,43,242,44,3,244,240,389,369,11,9,39,23,224,247,37,42,24,27,469,40,238,443,45,439,241,8,223,445,4,250,437,226,249,36,239,315,41,277,395,10,285,403,232,444,25,22,280,21,38,225}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{22,598,10,19,58,57,38,23,242,194,29,24,2,178,1580,5,3,91,1760,550,8,4,5,246,62,2262,3,283,20,1695,594,259,1,1001,513,2,2586,1984,114,553,1,60,64,2,1568,18,37,5,4,9,13,758,9,48,5}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
9;"{8,308,389,6,395,9,233,5,4,10,11,3,7,16}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{19,547,51,24,4,17335,42342,6,317,1447,377,30,11,26}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
10;"{469,389,229,230,11,231,232,242}";"{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}";"{15,2,17951,17058,4,5613,645,725}";"{USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD,USD}"
```

I copied the output from pgadmin3

Comment: Show your code and the output

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: *Off*: your `gme1` named CTE does nothing, just re-orders the columns from `gme` -- you can just safely drop it & select the columns in the right order within `gme` (or not, because it doesn't matter at all).

Comment: @pozs yes, thanks, this was actually a quick modification from another query. I will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an INTO statement in your select, which essentially takes your query and makes a new table in your database.

so like this should work

```
 SELECT distinct seller, buyer, currency, value, cost_type
     into gme   FROM iotable;
```

or you could do this, depending on what you want in the table

```
WITH gme AS(
        SELECT distinct seller, buyer, currency, value, cost_type
        FROM iotable
),
gme1 AS (
     Select seller, buyer, cost_type, value, currency
INTO MYNEWTABLE
 FROM gme
)
```

UPDATE:
The solution (using this method anyway) is as follows

```
      WITH gme AS(
                SELECT distinct seller, buyer, currency, value, cost_type
                FROM iotable
        ),
        gme1 AS (
             Select seller, buyer, cost_type, value, currency FROM gme
        )

    SELECT seller, 
    array_agg(buyer) as AGG_BUYER, 
    array_agg(cost_type) as AGG_CT, 
    array_agg(value) as AGG_VAL, 
    array_agg(currency) as AGG_CUR
/*this is where the new table is generated*/
        INTO MY_NEW_TABLE 
        FROM gme1 
        GROUP by seller
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line in the query, can you look at the query in question again? I want to store array in a new table and into didn't work with array.

Comment: While `select ... into ... from` does work in Postgres to create a new table, that syntax is deprecated and only there for backward compatibility. It is better to use the standard `create table xx as select ...` syntax

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `Create table` gives me a syntax error near `create`, probably because of `with`

Comment: yeah, I don't think CTE can be used in an inline create statement

Comment: And with `INTO`, I get `ERROR:  column "array_agg" specified more than once` error. Can I specify exact names of columns?

Comment: @khajvah I don't see that column at all in your query.... but you can rename columns inline ...select COL as NEWNAME... and the alias name will be written as the col name in the resulting table

Comment: @khajvah oh i see.... didn't see the update thoroughly, your result_agg function calls need to be aliased or they all have the same name

Comment: COL as NEWNAME worked, thanks a lot, I will accept the answer, as it is correct general answer, but you should update it to make it right for this case :)

Comment: You can of course use a CTE together with `create table as`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b1723/1. Btw: the second cte `gme1` is useless.